How to check if an object is overlapping with other named objects
I've seen someone do  this by making a box then detecting if the object is in the box which does work but only for a single object, how do i make it work for multiple objects, ty
Sub moveRight()
    Dim wall As Shape
    Dim char As Shape
    Dim i As Integer
    Set wall = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Wall")
    Set char = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Character")
    wallR = wall.Left - wall.Width
    wallB = wall.Top + wall.Height
    charR = char.Left - char.Width
    charB = char.Top + char.Height
    i = 1
    For i = 1 To 32
        char.Left = char.Left + 1
        If char.Left > wallR Then
            If Not wallB < char.Top Then
                If Not char.Top < wall.Top - char.Height Then
                    char.Left = char.Left - 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
    
    
    Next i
    

    

    
End Sub

I have 2 objects in my .pptm both of them called wall and i have code that makes my character move unless it touches the object called "wall." It works wonders when there is only 1 wall object but once there is 2 wall objects it fails to recognize the second one.

In theory, PPT doesn't allow multiple shapes with the same name on one slide, and tends to act up if you somehow manage to create them. For example, you reference ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Wall") ... that will return one shape only, probably the first of the two shapes with that name.  Give the other "Wall" a different name.
